# why we cannot add values directly in List<string> obj= new List<string>()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I want to make list of cities but when I try to add values in list it is giving error

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    cities.Add("pune");
    cities.Add("Mumbai");

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return cities ;
    }
}
```

I want to know why it is giving error while adding into the list?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `ArrayList<T>` nor `LinkedList<T>` is derrived from `List<T>` so obviously `List<string> cities = new ArrayList<string>();` **will not even compile**

Comment: cities.Add does not exist in the current context

Comment: This works totally fine.

Comment: Please update your question with the entire code (so where cities is declared, where you are trying to add to it)

Comment: What's wrong with this `List<string> cities = new List<string>() {"pune"};`?

Comment: obviously you cannot use `cities.Add("pune");` in class body it have to be in some method/constructor

Comment: it is working with    List<string> cities = new List<string>() {"pune"}; but why not with cities.Add("pune"); is my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write code like that in a class body

You have 2 options, either set the contents of your list when you declare it

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>() {"pune", "Mumbai"};
```

Alternatively you can do what you're currently doing, but move some of your code into the class' constructor

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();

    public ValuesController()
    {
        cities.Add("pune");
        cities.Add("Mumbai");
    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return cities ;
    }
}
```

Read more about class constructors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

You might also want to consider making `cities` a private field

Comment: but why second approoach is not working in a class body?

Comment: because that's how C# syntax is defined ... you should learn it (also because it would have no sens - in terms when this code should be called)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access your class members like that (`list.Add()`) outside a constructor or method body, that's simply not valid C#.

Member initialization code is moved to the constructor by the compiler. So if you `new` a field, that `new` actually lives in the (implicitly generated or explicitly declared) constructor.

So for readability's sake, simply create a constructor and move the initialization code into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

C# currently does not and will probably never support the code you have written, but that isn't to say that you can't achieve something similar.

For example, if you were to declare a `string[]` instead of a `List<string>` then you are able to declare the values in the way that you desire.

In addition, the `.ToList<string>()` method can be used to return a List too.

Here is your modified code:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private string[] cities = { "pune", "Mumbai" }; // cities is now an array of string

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return cities.ToList<string>(); // .ToList<string>() method returns cities as a List<string>

    }

}
```